# Libgdx - большое расстояние от начала координат 3D пространстве

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

Здравствуйте, изучаю libgdx 3D
Использую FirstPersonCameraController(PerspectiveCamera)

Есть объекты (Модели) в 3D пространстве. 
Если они расположены на большом расстоянии от начала координат (0,0,0), то при приближении к ним и вращении камеры происходит искажение (дерганье) объекта в проекции, складывается ощущение что просто перескакивает пиксели.
Чем дальше от центра координат, тем хуже.

Например, если объект размером 0.03f то при расстоянии в 50.0f от центра координат уже есть искажения. Ну и естественно если объект больше то и расстояния другие.

Я думаю это все из за того что 3d пространство в openGL для расчетов использует float, и матрица тоже. При double возможно результат был-бы лучше.

Как побороть данную проблему?

Comment: @Kromster зависит от размера объекта. Если объект размером 0.03f то при расстоянии в 50.0f от центра координат уже есть искажения. Ну и естественно если объект больше то и расстояния другие.

Comment: А есть возможность записать видео и продемонстрировать проблему?

Comment: @Unick https://youtu.be/KSsWD6I9N_k   И еще заметил, чем дальше камера, то нужно делать больше объект. Та же сфера в 0.13f, на расстоянии в 6000f превращается в хрен знает что.

Comment: А каким образом вы меняете позицию? Возможно у вы меняете позицию на слишком больше число и получаете дёргание. Но насколько я знаю если вы хотите рендерить объекты на большом расстоянии, например рендер планет солнечной системы, но стандарные средства OpenGL вам могут не подойти.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю стоит смотреть в сторону MIP-MAP Filtering, хотя более детально можно будет говорить только после более полного описания проблемы

[MIP-MAP Filtering](http://www.ixbt.com/video/mip-mapping.html)

Comment: О текстурах в вопросе ни слова.

Comment: в вопросе вообще мало про что написано, это как гадание на кофейной гуще. Я имел в виду что похожий на описанный вами эффект наблюдается при наложении на объект текстур без уменьшения их размера при значительном уменьшении размера модели по отношению к камере.

Comment: Поэтому, вместо гадания, лучше попросить автра уточнить вопрос, перед тем как давать не относящийся к теме вопрос. С другой стороны, если у вас есть опыт в решении другого вопроса, то вы можете сами разместить такой вопрос и дать на него ответ.